# Incorrect Signs on Tangent Planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So basically I've calculated a tangent plane to a surface, and a normal line for that plane through the point where the surface touches the plane, and I'm getting signs opposite to the professor's answer.

The original question is "Let $S$ be a circular paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 - z = 1$. Find a) find gradient vector and its magnitude at $(1,2)$ and b) the equations of the tangent plane and normal line to $S$ at $(1,2)$."

This seems pretty simple to me. For part a, the gradient vector should only be in terms of $x$ and $y$ since it defines a $z$, so I come up with $\delta F = <2,4>$ and a magnitude of $2\sqrt{5}$.

For part b, I know I need a $z$ value and partial derivative of $z$ since equations on planes and lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ require that. So if $(x,y) = (1,2)$, $z = 1^2 + 2^2 - 1 = 4$. So the point $(1,2,4)$ is on the plane and the line goes through it.

Finally, plugging all these into the equation for a plane, I get $2(x-1) + 4(y-2) - 1(z-4) = 0$ so $2x + 4y - z = 6$. It also follows that if a line is $x = x_0 + at$, $y = y_0 + bt$, $z = z_0 + ct$, then my line equations are $x = 1 + 2t$, $y = 2+4t$, $z = 4 - t$.

However, while my instructor's answer for the tangent plane is the same, her line is $x = 1 - 2t$, $y = 2 - 4t$, $z = 4 + t$.

What did I mess up?

Comment: $t\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $-t\in\mathbb{R}$. Just set $s=-t$.

Comment: My apologies, I don't follow what you mean. Are you saying that because t is in the set of all reals, you can just arbitrarily choose its opposite sign? Why would the instructor do that?

Comment: The variable $t$ is not a particular number, it is a free parameter that runs along $\mathbb{R}$. Changing the sign does not change anything, $s=-t$ is  again a free parameter that sweeps the same set.